# Slide to unlock with Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver, slide

I have to simulate unlocking this slide with Selenium. Once dragged to the end, a function should start. 
But I can't, what can I do?

I have tried with:

```
Action action = (Action) move.dragAndDropBy (slider, 10, 0) .build ();
```

the cursor moves but nothing starts

Then I tried with:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript ( "javascript: document.getElementById(\"slider\").value = 100;");
```

the problem is that this is not the classic slider, it is a range type input, connected to a JS.
I am attaching the code

```
<input ng-disabled="ngDisabled" id="Slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" ng-change="setMoving()" ng-model="ngModel" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-step ng-dirty ng-touched" style="">


   function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("widgets").directive("Slider", ["TranslationService", "$timeout", "$compile", "$log", function(e, a, t, i) {
        return i.debug("slider directive called"), {
            require: ["ngModel"],
            templateUrl: "slider/template/slider.html",
            scope: {
                ngModel: "=",
                sliderParams: "=",
                min: "@",
                max: "@",
                step: "@",
                labelKey: "@",
                sliderCallback: "&",
                ngDisabled: "="
            },
            replace: !0,
            link: function(t, i) {
                var o = i.find("input");
                angular.isObject(t.sliderParams) || (t.sliderParams = {
                    callback: !1,
                    value: 0,
                    step: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100
                }), t.labelKey && (t.label = e.getLabelFromKey(t.labelKey, "label")), t.sliderParams.callback && function(e, t) {
                    o.bind("mouseup", function() {
                        parseInt(e.ngModel) === parseInt(e.sliderParams.max) && e.moving ? (e.moving = !1, e.clicked = !1, e.$eval(e.$parent.sliderCallback), e.sliderParams.value = 0, a(function() {
                            $("#Slider").val(0)
                        }, 100)) : (e.ngModel = 0, e.moving = !1, a(function() {
                            $("#Slider").val(0)
                        }, 100))
                    })
                }(t), t.setMoving = function() {
                    parseInt(t.ngModel) <= parseInt(t.sliderParams.max / 5) && (t.moving = !0)
                }
            }
        }
    }])
}(),
```

### CSS

```
   .slider-container {
  /* thumb */ }
  .slider-container input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: url(../images/icons/slider-body.png) no-repeat center center #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    outline: none;
    /* no focus outline */ }
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    border: inherit;
    background: transparent; }
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
    border: inherit;
    color: transparent;
    /* don't drawn vertical reference line */
    background: transparent; }
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower,
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: transparent; }
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none; }
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: url(../images/icons/slider-thumb.png) no-repeat center center; }
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: url(../images/icons/slider-thumb.png) no-repeat center center; }
  .slider-container input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
    width: 30px;
    height: 26px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: url(../images/icons/slider-thumb.png) no-repeat center center; }
  .slider-container.disabled input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: url(../images/icons/slider-thumb-disabled.png) no-repeat center center; }
  .slider-container.disabled input[type="range"] {
    background-color: #ccc;
    background-image: none; }
```

Comment: I would try sending keys to it to set a numeric value....

Comment: i can't use selenium's "sendKey".  it is not a text input field.

Comment: yeah, just tested it and it doesn't seem to work.  Right/left arrow key does though, so you could loop it to send the proper incrememt:  element.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);

Comment: You will likely need to interact with the shadow DOM that represents the range slider.

Comment: but I can move the arrow from left to right.  I just don't understand why the function doesn't trigger when I get to the end.  while with the mouse it obviously works.  normally you have to click drag to the end and release

Comment: looks like it may want the mouse to be moving when you generate a mouse-up event.  Meaning you have to drag this bar while releasing the mousebutton.  Try it manually and let go of the button while the mouse is not moving and the slider is at 100... does it submit?